Trouble with Type Safety in Hono Zod Validation Middleware
I've been working on implementing a validation middleware in Hono using Zod and @hono/zod-validator. Here's the code snippet of the middleware:
const validationMiddleware = (schema: ZodSchema, target: keyof ValidationTargets) => {
    return createMiddleware(async (c, next) => {
        await next()
        zValidator(target, schema, (result, c) => {
            if (!result.success) {
                return c.json({
                    success: false,
                    error: {
                        code: 400,
                        message: result.error.issues[0].message,
                        innerError: {
                            timestamp: new Date(Date.now())
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}

And I use it like this:
validationMiddleware(userValidation, 'json')

The issue I'm facing is that I can't seem to get type safety on the return value. Specifically, when I try to use c.req.valid('json'), TypeScript throws the following error:
TS2345: Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never on the 'json' input

I'm puzzled about why TypeScript is inferring never instead of the expected type. Could someone please advise on how to resolve this and ensure type safety in this scenario? Thanks!

This will be hard to answer without a minimal reproducible example. When I tried to make one (see: https://tsplay.dev/wE0p4W), I found I had no idea where all this imported things were coming from, so I can't reproduce the issue. If you [edit] your question to include a minimal example that shows the type error you are getting, then we should be able to help you much better.

I was experimenting with hono was poking at a type issue myself and I think the problem may be upstream.
I'm sorry this is not the ideal answer you're looking for! I decided to submit post as an answer vs. a comment to your question because I think it is relevant.
I took a look at the code and discovered there's a nasty // @ts-expect-error suppressing TypeScript errors in the code of the current release of @hono/zod-validator in arguably the most important spot:
  // @ts-expect-error not typed well
  validator(target, async (value, c) => {
    // ...

https://github.com/honojs/middleware/blob/main/packages/zod-validator/src/index.ts#L43
This calls the validity of any of the typing into question.
I absolutely hate it when libraries promote something as if its production-ready and type-safe when the code has cheats and escape hatches that clobber types when you use them (cough react-hook-form cough react-table).
In fairness its a v0 release however I think it should be tagged beta and the docs should have a warning about this.
On a positive note --
The code itself is actually quite simple and your project most likely doesn't need all the complex generic typing that hono's trying to do. It's a different beast to write a general-case library solution for a public package with support for extra features like hooks.
If the only reason you're using @hono/zod-validator is because it runs zodSchema.safeParseAsync(...) for you plus return c.json(result, 400) then I'm sure you'd agree that you don't really need this package at all.
You can incorporate the functionality into your own middleware and I suspect you'll be able to resolve your type issues within your own codebase.

A day later: I will add that hono's validator + zod-validator types are so poor that instead of messing with middleware I created helper functions that throw custom errors, and then I use app.onError() handler to send a formatted response (this can also handle ZodError's if you don't want to add custom errors). The syntax is cleaner and fewer LOC than official examples that add a chain of middleware validators to routes and the typing is all correct.

I have answered a similar question here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/79300489/15461314, you can take a look. Your code can look like this then -
type ZodInputSchema<T extends keyof ValidationTargets, U extends z.ZodType> = {
  in: {
    [K in T]: z.input<U>;
  };
  out: {
    [K in T]: z.infer<U>;
  };
};

const validationMiddleware = <
  T extends z.ZodSchema,
  U extends keyof ValidationTargets,
  E extends Env,
  P extends string,
  I extends ZodInputSchema<U, T>
>(
  schema: T,
  target: U
) => {
  return createMiddleware<E, P, I>(async (c, next) => {
    await next();
    zValidator(target, schema, (result, c) => {
      if (!result.success) {
        return c.json({
          success: false,
          error: {
            code: 400,
            message: result.error.issues[0].message,
            innerError: {
              timestamp: new Date(Date.now()),
            },
          },
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

// Usage
app.get("/sample", validationMiddleware(schema, "json"));

